# Android Icon not showing on 2.2 emulator but showing on 1.6

Tags: java, android

How do i fix this?
I have icon.png in my hdpi drawable and my mdpi drawable. I am guessing it has something to do with the hdpi drawable. the hdpi version of the icon is spelled correctly and is 72x72 whereas the mdpi is 48x48.

I also tried cleaning the project too. I have no coding except for the template HelloWorld .java file.

Oh it works on the Google 2.2 Emulator but not the Android 2.2 Emulator. Any suggestions?

Comment: do both emulator have the same size and resolution ? And what about your support for multiple screens in your manifest ?

Comment: are you try to put icon parth in manifest file? if yes then update it

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had issues with a replacement icon displaying in an emulator, it was because Eclipse needed the directory to be refreshed before it would see the new version and send it to the emulator.  If this is the cause of your issue, right-click on the drawables folder and select refresh, then run the application in the emulator again.  Eclipse should send the new version over and it should appear as expected.